# Extend jQuery with enable/disable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an extended disable/enable function in jQuery. This is working, but is this the best solution? Is each loop necessary?

```
 $.fn.ariaDisabled = function (isDisabled) {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Sets the disabled state.
        /// </summary>
        return this.each(function () {

            var $item = $(this);

            if (isDisabled === true) {
                $item
                    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                    .attr('aria-disabled', 'true')
                    .addClass('disabled');
            }
            else {
                $item
                    .removeAttr('disabled')
                    .removeAttr('aria-disabled')
                    .removeClass('disabled');
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: If the function is called `ariaDisabled` then it should only change the `[aria-disabled]` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall it looks quite nice.
Just a few points:

- The parameter name is asking a question about the element, not making a statement of what to do. I would rename it to `disable` which enables the caller to better signify their intent.
- In the same vein, I would also rename the function to `ariaDisable` as it performs an action as opposed to asking a question

#### Edit

Per [m90](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62853/m90)'s comment the loop is per jQuery plugin conventions as noted [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method)